# select COUNT(Id) AS Total from `euro` where (N1 = $i or N2 = $i or N3 = $i or N4 = $i or N5 = $i) LIMIT 50

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, sql-limit

```
select COUNT(Id) AS Total 
from `euro` 
where (N1 = $i or N2 = $i or N3 = $i or N4 = $i or N5 = $i) 
LIMIT 50
```

How to count only 50 results??

I've tryied this with no sucess

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM euro where (N1 = $i or N2 = $i or N3 = $i or N4 = $i or N5 = $i) LIMIT 50";
$query = "select COUNT(Id) As Total FROM ($sql) as a"
```

or this:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM euro  LIMIT 50";
$query = "select COUNT(Id) As Total FROM ($sql) as a where (N1 = $i or N2 = $i or N3 = $i or N4 = $i or N5 = $i)"
```

I'm not quite sure if I understand last part on results give all 50

I have this table:

Id   date  dayofweek  N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 E1 E2

1  2004-02-13 Friday  1  4  12 41 50  1 4

2  2004-02-28 Friday  2  5  32 33 39  4 6

3  2004-03-10 Tuesday 23 26 43 44 49  9 10

I had this:
$query = "select COUNT(Id) AS Total from `euro` where (N1 = $i or N2 = $i or N3 = $i or N4 = $i or N5 = $i)";
And it worked counting in an efficient way for all the records in table so it means it must respect that part.

Now I have :

$query = "select COUNT(N1) As Total  FROM (SELECT * FROM `euro` where $i in (N1, N2, N3, N4, N5) Order By Id Desc LIMIT 50) a";

And it gives 50 to all counting... I can't understand...

Answer (score 0):

You  would typically select the records in a subquery first, then aggregate:

```
select count(id) as total 
from (
    select id
    from euro 
    where ? in (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
    order by ??
    limit 50
) t
```

Notes:

- `limit` without `order by` does not give you a stable result; I added an `order by` clause, in which you would need to put the relevant sorting column
- `in` is handy to avoid repeating `or` conditions
- use parameters; don't concatenate variables in the query string, this is inefficient - and, more important, unsafe if the value comes from outside your code
- `count(<column>)` takes in account everything but `null` values; for the query to make sense *at all*, `id` should be a nullable column; if it does not contain any `null` value, the query is guaranteed to return `50` (or the total number of records in the table, if that's less than `50`)

Comment: It gives me 50 in all values

Comment: @JoaoMarques: this is not necessarily suprising - see the last bullet point in my answer.

Comment: I had this: $query = "select COUNT(Id) AS Total from euro where (N1 = $i or N2 = $i or N3 = $i or N4 = $i or N5 = $i)"; And it worked counting in an efficient way for all the records in table so it means it must respect that part , only when I try to LIMIT 50 it worked out wrong

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing this:

$query= "SELECT Id FROM `euro` Order By Id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$resultados = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$query= "SELECT COUNT(Id) As Total FROM `euro` where $i in (N1, N2, N3, N4, N5) AND (Id > ($resultados -50)) Order By Id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);